# Accessing DataTables in DataSet with table name

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset

I am currently writing a program that receives 3 Tables from SQL, with the data from each table I am using and row to create an object of a corresponding class.

After debugging step by step I can see that the data inside the DataSet in indeed correct, but I can't seem to access it by name.
When I access the tables inside the dataset using their index it works perfectly, like this -

```
DataSet ds = new ProgramProcedures().GetTestByUser(UserId);                                    
if (ds.Tables[0].IsHasRows())
{
    foreach (DataRow _dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        TestList.Add(new Test(_dr));
    }
}
```

When I try to access it by name it fails and doesn't enter the if statment.

```
DataSet ds = new ProgramProcedures().GetTestByUser(UserId);
if (ds.Tables["Name1"].IsHasRows())
{
    foreach (DataRow _dr in ds.Tables["Name1"].Rows)
    {
        TestList.Add(new Test(_dr));
    }
}
```

Inside the stored procedure the data comes from I included the following lines -

```
@tables nvarchar(max)='' output
set @tables='Name1,Name2,Name3'
```

When debugging and inspecting the content of the ds variable, the data is correct but the names of the tables are "Table, Table1, Table2"
What am I doing wrong? I would like to access the tables by name since it makes the code more reliable in case any changes are made to it or the procedure.

I've tried using the indexes of the table instead of their names, this worked perfectly, but I would like to use the names of the tables.

Comment: What is `IsHasRows`?

Comment: IsHasRows is an inhouse function used to determine if a DataTable has rows, when I access the table by index the condition is met, when I try to access by name it isn't

Comment: The tables' names are auto generated in a DataSet unless you don't use `DataAdapter.Fill(table, tableName)`. I also don't see where you consume the output parameter. You could use  a [custom DataAdapter](https://web.archive.org/web/20141005072324/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728893(VS.71).aspx) with a table mapping or add the table-name to the select query so you can process it from the first DataRow. Maybe it's the simplest to stay with the index approach if you can ensure that the order is as expected.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the DataAdapter.filler?
The index approach is simple but it is much less dynamic and reliable, any change in the procedure / C# process and mess with the functionality of this program

Comment: If the data is coming from Excel you need a dollar sign in front of the name.  The dollar sign indicates the table is a System Table.

Comment: It looks like what you're actually trying to do here is to populate `TestList`, which is presumably a `List<Test>`. If we assume that: we we actually even need the `DataSet` here? Tools like EF or Dapper make it trivial to go straight from raw SQL to populated objects, without using `DataTable`/`DataSet` as intermediate steps - even for multi-result-grid queries. Are you interested in options that go this route?

Answer (score 1):

The table names are auto generated from the number of tables in the DataSet, so your output parameter is not mapped automagically. I also don't see where you are consuming it.

I have created a sample DB and SP and it worked without a problem:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetTestByUser 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @UserId int, 
    @TableNames nvarchar(max) = '' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    set @TableNames = 'Name1,Name2,Name3'

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * FROM Table1
    SELECT * FROM Table2
END
GO
```

You need to consume the data to be able to retrieve the output parameter. So either close a `SqlDataReader` explicitely or use a builtin method like `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` that closes the connection at the end. Then you can read the out-value and modify the DataSet's table-names:

```
using SqlConnection con = new(connectionString);
using SqlCommand command = new("dbo.GetTestByUser", con);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", 1);
SqlParameter tableNamesOutParameter = new("@TableNames", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000)
{ Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
command.Parameters.Add(tableNamesOutParameter);

using SqlDataAdapter da = new(command);
DataSet ds = new();
da.Fill(ds);
string[] tableNames = tableNamesOutParameter.Value?.ToString()?.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries) ?? Array.Empty<string>();
// now change the table-names to the correct ones retrived from the SP
for (int i = 0; i < tableNames.Length; i++)
{
    ds.Tables[i].TableName = tableNames[i];
}

// now you can access each table by the correct name:
DataTable? table1 = ds.Tables["Name1"];
if (table1?.AsEnumerable().Any() == true)
{
    foreach (DataRow _dr in table1.Rows)
    {
        TestList.Add(new Test(_dr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue.

I did not pass a @tables param into the stored procedure, once I did that everything worked like clockwork.

Thank you for your time and effort, much appreciated